# I am configuring Firebase 9.6.2 to my web app JavaScript but getting a lot of errors that prevent this operation, the error and code is below

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code is below

WHERE ERROR :
{
"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 242,
"colno": 15
}

I need to configure this app using the latest version of firebase in 2022 and this has been an issue, any fixes?
Tried putting all the Javascript in one place but it still gave multiple errors.

```js
/*import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAtzy40xFuSImG9HgnZ_wwrvFXZv3T40Pc",
    authDomain: "tiprock-c4967.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tiprock-c4967.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tiprock-c4967",
    storageBucket: "tiprock-c4967.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "103862559440",
    appId: "1:103862559440:web:8e5636b52cb4516680f4d5",
    measurementId: "G-S4Q531K4HR"

});  */
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAtzy40xFuSImG9HgnZ_wwrvFXZv3T40Pc",
    authDomain: "tiprock-c4967.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tiprock-c4967.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tiprock-c4967",
    storageBucket: "tiprock-c4967.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "103862559440",
    appId: "1:103862559440:web:8e5636b52cb4516680f4d5",
    measurementId: "G-S4Q531K4HR"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
 

//Reference messages
 var message= firebase.database().ref('messages');

//Listen for a submittion from the form
document.getElementById('postcreation').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Submission is working');
  //gET VALUES
  var title = getInput('title');
  var time = getInput('time');
  var author = getInput('author');
  var content = getInput('content');

  
  //test if the function below works
  //console.log(title);

  //Calling our data
  saveMessages(title, time, author, content);

  //Confirm saving and submission
}

//Function to fetch form values
function getInput(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

//Save msgs to firebse
function saveMessages(title, time, author, message){
    var newMessageRef = message.push();
    newMessageRef.set({
        title:title,
        time:time,
        author:author,
        content:content
    })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:wght@100;400&family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@100;200&family=Roboto:wght@100&family=The+Nautigal:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    
}
/*Different sizes*/
/*font-family: 'Be Vietnam Pro', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'The Nautigal', cursive;*/
body{
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header-cont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #000;
    
}
.header-cont>h1{
    font-family: 'The Nautigal', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(10%);
}
.header-cont>ul>li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    
}
.header-cont>ul{
    transform: translateX(10%);
    margin: 5px;
}

/*Blog main container*/
.post-maincont{
    width:70%;
    border: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #11bb7a;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px #ccc;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transform: translateX(10%);
}
.post{
    margin: 15px;
    
}
.post>h3{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Be Vietnam Pro', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(71, 70, 70);
    margin: 10px;
}
.date{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgb(73, 206, 133);
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.post>p{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:rgb(44, 44, 44);
    font-weight: 700;
    
}

.formHeading{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'The Nautigal', cursive;
    font-weight: 600;
    transform: translateX(10%);
}
form{
    margin: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
.textP{
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #ccc;
}
.textP>label{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(49, 49, 4);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.textP>input{
    border: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(182, 182, 182);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
input{
    outline: none;
}
button{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #11bb7a;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{
    background: #10ac70;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>blog test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-cont">
        <h1>Tech Spot</h1>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
            <li>Reach Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!--Blog posts-->
    <div class="post-maincont">
        <div class="post">
            <h3>Oragon Contest</h3>
            <div class="date">Thursday, 7.18 pm</div>
            <p class="author">Author: Peter Jeans</p>
            
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates totam nisi dolore deserunt eveniet aut maiores, natus qui recusandae! Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum voluptatibus placeat a consectetur libero rem nobis.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Make post form-->
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h2 class="formHeading">Make Your Post</h2>
    <form action="" id="postcreation">
        <div class="textP">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Put title here...">
        </div>

        <div class="textP">
            <label for="time">Time and date</label>
            <input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="e.g. Tue, 4.30 am">
        </div>

        <div class="textP">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="e.g. James Blake">
        </div>

        <div class="textP">
            <label for="content">Content</label>
            <input type="text" name="content" id="content" placeholder="Write here...">
        </div>

        <div class="button"><button type="submit">Post</button></div>
    </form>
    <!--Javascript linked-->
   <script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  
</script>
    <script  src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncomment the `import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';` line ?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you haven't installed the `firebase` npm package
you can install it by running the following command

```
npm install firebase
```

or if you don't want to use npm or nodejs just go with firebase cdn URLs

extracts from the following [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#:%7E:text=Do%20you%20use,bundler%20for%20production.)

```
Do you use ESM and want to use browser modules? Replace all your import lines to use the following pattern:
import { } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-SERVICE.js'
(where SERVICE is an SDK name such as firebase-firestore).
Using browser modules is a quick way to get started, but we recommend using a module bundler for production.
```